# How to use https connection in nodejs?

Tags: php, node.js, ssl, https

I am using Nginx+PHP setup to run PHP pages with 80 port. And also using nodejs with 8080 port. Now i want to connect SSL(https) connection for Nodejs.

How can be it is achievable? Pls.

Comment: locally right?.

Comment: Yes locally .....

Comment: will you be using express for nodejs or just node.js

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: No express... just nodejs within the PHP page.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities to achieve what you're trying to do :

**1. Setting your SSL through Nginx**

This way you will be able to use your SSL Certificate on your PHP sites aswell. To achieve that, you'll have to set some rules in your virtual hosts file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/foo`.
In the following example I've created a subdomain api.lvh.me (lvh.me redirecting to localhost)

```
server {
     listen 443 ssl;
     server_name api.lvh.me;

     ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /path/to/certificate.key;

     location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

**2. Setting HTTPS directly on your Nodejs server**

I won't go into details, everything is written on Nodejs's documentation ([HTTPS Nodejs Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html))

Comment: "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:64
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: I want to use nodejs within the PHP page.

Comment: var url = window.location.host;
var socket = io.connect('http://' + url + ':8080', {secure: true});